# Opening a window and getting its URL?

Tags: java, security, applet, java-web-start

Are java applets capable of opening new browser windows and retrieving their end URL?

Comment: For pretty much the same reason you cannot drive your applet to work.

Comment: Yeah that sounds logical.

Answer (score 2):

> Are java applets capable of opening new browser windows and retrieving their end URL?

No, and it is really none of the applet's business.  It is a security thing.

Imagine you control an applet that opens an innocuous window.  I get bored with that and reuse the window to surf over to BigBustyBabes.com instead.  That final URL is not something I (as a user) would want your applet to know.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/applet/Opening-a-URL-from-an-Applet.shtml) might help with opening a new URL, but from the same browser window. However assuming that you can reach the path where a browser is, you could easily run it. However I think this can be done easier with javascript, at least the part with retrieving the end URL, javascript seems to be the solution.

For opening a [new window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) with javascript: `window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)`.
For retrieving a URL with javascript use `document.URL`

Comment: I tried js , but you can not get the final url it redirects to.

Comment: @Naughty.Coder `var currURL=document.URL`